# What is the irradiance of an extended source?

Tags: electromagnetism, calculus, radiometry

For example, what is the irradiance at a certain A = 2m^2 surface from a  P = 10W tube lamp with significant radius and length - say, r = 15mm L = 100mm - measured at a small distance - say, d = 2m? Would the inverse-square law apply to such a case?

I've tried finding answers elsewhere, but they only come up with regards to point sources.

Comment: If you are given a total radiant power of $10 \, \rm W$ for the whole lamp, you should be able to divide by the total surface area (assuming the radiant properties are uniform across the surface in the absence of any info to the contrary), which would give $W/m^2$.  Then you probably have to account for view factors between the source area and the target area. It is a non trivial calculation, but tables of view factors exist for this simple geometry

Comment: One resource http://www.thermalradiation.net/tablecon.html

Comment: Oh wow, that's a great site. Thanks so much!

For future reference, these are especially useful for tube lamps:

http://www.thermalradiation.net/sectionc/C-74.html - For finite cylider and finite plane

http://www.thermalradiation.net/sectionc/C-61.html -  For infinite cylinder and infinite plane